# What are the secret codes for LEGO Harry Potter Years 1-4?

Tags: cheats, lego-harry-potter-years-1-4

The codes unlock things like money multipliers and other cheats.

Comment: Not familiar with this game. Should this be tagged as a cheat?

Comment: @hobodave - they're in-game "cheats". You normally find items in the levels that unlock them, but you can also enter a code to get the "cheat" earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are all the cheat codes:

- `AUC8EH` – Carrot Wands
- `H27KGC` – Character Studs
- `HA79V8` – Character Token Detector
- `T7PVVN` – Christmas
- `4DMK2R` – Disguise
- `J9U6Z9` – Extra Hearts
- `ZEX7MV` – Fall Rescue
- `Z9BFAD` – Fast Dig
- `FA3GQA` – Fast Magic
- `84QNQN` – Gold Brick Detector
- `TTMC6D` – Hogwarts Crest Detector
- `F88VUW` – Ice Rink
- `QQWC6B` – Invincibility
- `7AD7HE` – Red Brick Detector
- `89ML2W` – Regenerate Hearts
- `H8X69Y` – Score x10
- `74YKR7` – Score x2
- `J3WHNK` – Score x4
- `XK9ANE` – Score x6
- `HUFV2H` – Score x8
- `HZBVX7` – Silhouttes
- `BMEU6X` – Singing Mandrake
- `67FKWZ` – Stud Magnet

Red Bricks Cheat Codes

- `AUC8EH` – Carrot Wands
- `H27KGC` – Character Studs
- `HA79V8` – Character Token Detector
- `T7PVVN` – Christmas
- `J9U6Z9` – Extra Hearts
- `Z9BFAD` – Fast Dig
- `FA3GQA` – Fast Magic
- `84QNQN` – Gold Brick Detector
- `TTMC6D` – Hogwarts Crest Detector
- `F88VUW` – Ice Rink
- `7AD7HE` – Red Brick Detector
- `89ML2W` – Regenerate Hearts
- `HZBVX7` – Silhouettes
- `BMEU6X` – Singing Mandrake
- `67FKWZ` – Stud Magnet

Years 1-4 Gold Bricks Cheat Codes

- `QE4VC7` – Gold Brick 01
- `FY8H97` – Gold Brick 02
- `3MQT4P` – Gold Brick 03
- `PQPM7Z` – Gold Brick 04
- `ZY2CPA` – Gold Brick 05
- `3GMTP6` – Gold Brick 06
- `XY6VYZ` – Gold Brick 07
- `TUNC4W` – Gold Brick 08
- `EJ42Q6` – Gold Brick 09
- `GFJCV9` – Gold Brick 10
- `DZCY6G` – Gold Brick 11

Spells Cheat Codes

- `VE9VV7` – Accio
- `QFB6NR` – Anteoculatia
- `6DNR6L` – Calvorio
- `9GJ442` – Colovaria
- `CD4JLX` – Engorgio Skullus
- `MYN3NB` – Entomorphis
- `ND2L7W` – Flipendo
- `ERA9DR` – Glacius
- `H8FTHL` – Herbifors
- `YEB9Q9` – Incarcerous
- `2M2XJ6` – Locomotor Mortis
- `JK6QRM` – Multicorfors
- `UW8LRH` – Redactum Skullus

Source: [Mejoress](https://www.mejoress.com/en/lego-harry-potter-cheat-codes-years-1-4-5-7/)

Answer (score 4):

There's quite a sizable list [here](http://www.cheatscodesguides.com/wii-cheats/lego-harry-potter/). An extract:

> Head to the Wiseacres Wizarding Equipment in the Leaky Cauldron hub area. It can be found in Diagon Alley. You can enter the following codes upstairs for the desired effect.
>
> - AUC8EH - Carrot Wands
> - H27KGC - Character Studs
> - HA79V8 - Character Token Detector